# What do these sentences mean?

Tags: translation, words, set-phrases, phrases

Recently, I heard (in a song) these 3 sentences and I can't translate some words in them. I've tried various translators but I'm still confused, so I hope you can help me. Sentences are.

紡いだ日々もあるよ

本当はいつもどんな場面にも「誰か」がいたんだ (In this one. I just don't understand 「本当はいつも」)

花束も約束もいらないただいくつもの愛でこの空は繋がってるよ (In this one. I just don't understand 「いくつもの愛で」)

Comment: Did you check a dictionary? [幾つも on Weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%B9%BE%E3%81%A4%E3%82%82) [幾]{いく}つもの = many; a great number of (or, are you confused with the usage of the で?)　[本当は on Weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%9C%AC%E5%BD%93%E3%81%AF) ・[いつも on Weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A4%E3%82%82)

Comment: 紡いだ doesn't mean "perfect". It can be "We had, spent, lived, shared..." etc. depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

1) `There are days where we are together`. `紡いだ` I think of as weaving the fabric of the day by being together.

2)

> 本当はいつも

means `In truth, there has always...`. Note the `has` is because the sentence is overall past tense. So it means overall like: `In truth, there has always been a certain someone there, regardless of the situation I was in`

3)  `いくつも` as choco pointed out means `a great many`. The phrase is actually two sentences:

花束も約束もいらない: `I don't need flowers or promises`.

ただいくつもの愛でこの空は繋がってるよ: `After all, our loves connect the entire sky together.`

Comment: It doesn't say "**I only need for our enormous love** to connect..."

Comment: Isn't the で here used to indicate place? And ただ mean `I only need` because it transitions from the previous phrase? Perhaps `いくつもの愛` should be `all the loves` instead? Does it refer to loves outside the speaker as well?

Comment: ①"Isn't the で here used to indicate place" >> No, the で is [goo辞書 #❶-6](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/148951/m0u/%E3%81%A7/) 「動作・作用の手段・方法・材料などを表す。」i.e. It's the instrumental case. ②"ただ mean I only need" >> No, it doesn't say "I need..." but it's describing how the sky is connected, linked, tied or united together, with all your friends' love/friendship. ③"Perhaps いくつもの愛 should be all the loves instead? Does it refer to loves outside the speaker as well?">> Yes, it refers to all the loves and friendship of the speaker/reader and their friends that supported them (=「誰か」,

Comment: (cont.) 「ひとりひとり　かけがえのない“キミ”」and「みんな」 in [the lyrics here](http://www.littleoslo.com/lyj/home/%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A1-aimer-%E3%82%AD%E3%82%BA%E3%83%8A-%E6%AD%8C%E8%A9%9E-pv/)). You'll understand if you read the whole lyrics.

Comment: @choco: Thanks for you taking your time to help me understand my mistakes. Is there any source that says `紡いだ` is spending days together? Or am I supposed to understand that as `we weave the story of our days` by means of being together?

Comment: Actually, that makes perfect sense. I don't know why I didn't think of that earlier...